# Adding border to svg polygon by using filters

Tags: svg, filter

I am looking for a way to add a border to a polygon with SVG. I can't add a another polygon since it should work independently from polygon shape. 
I tried using stroke on polygon but it also draws the line inside the polygon. Drawing only outside of the polygon was removed recently latest W3C specs.

So I fiddled with svg filters and it nearly works but I got to point that the border is a bit cut. Does anyone know how to remove this unwanted effect?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qgt5yvs4/)

Code:

```
` <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{fill:#feb500;}
        </style>
        <filter id="solid-border" width="130%">
            <feFlood flood-color="black" result="base"/>
            <feMorphology result="bigger" in="SourceGraphic" operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
            <feComposite result="drop" in="base" in2="bigger" operator="in"/>
            <feMerge>
                <feMergeNode in="drop"/>
                <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
            </feMerge>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="drop" mode="normal"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id="background" filter="url(#solid-border)">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="64 13 6.5 107 121.5 107 64 13"/>
    </g>
</svg>`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create neater rounded corners by using the blur-then-threshold trick.

We are blurring a black triangle, then using a `feComponentTransfer` primitive to convert dark greys to black and the lighter greys to white.

You can adjust the "stroke" size by changing `stdDeviation`, or varying the number of `1`s in the `tableValues` attribute.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{fill:#feb500;}
        </style>
        <filter id="solid-border2" width="130%" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-color="black" result="base"/>
            <feGaussianBlur result="blur" in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/>
            <feComponentTransfer in="blur" result="threshold">
              <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="threshold" mode="normal"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id="background" filter="url(#solid-border2)">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="64 13 6.5 107 121.5 107"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If you wanted, you could also apply this trick to your version of the filter.  However, the corners get a bit funky.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{fill:#feb500;}
        </style>
        <filter id="solid-border" width="130%">
            <feFlood flood-color="black" result="base"/>
            <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="4"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
            <feComponentTransfer>
              <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 1 1 1 1 1"/>
            </feComponentTransfer>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="drop" mode="normal"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id="background" filter="url(#solid-border)">
        <polygon class="cls-1" points="64 13 6.5 107 121.5 107"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like below. Declaring the xlink namespace in svg tag as without it, Safari doesn't support the use tag.
You're defining the shape after you use the use tag. The internal stroke in the use tag is covered by the original shape after. Though I'm unsure if this is using another polygon as you say can't use one.

```
 <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
        <defs>
            <style>
                .cls-1{fill:#feb500;}
            </style>
        </defs>
        <use xlink:href="#triangleShape" stroke="black" stroke-width="8"/>
        <polygon id="triangleShape" class="cls-1" points="64 13 6.5 107 121.5 107 64 13"/>
    </svg>
```